# How to kill an outside process using python?

Tags: python

I am creating a python programme which will first run **another** python file and then every **5 mins** it will terminate it and restart it untill I manually stop it

I used **call** from **subprocess** to start the file every 5 mins but how can I terminate it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

Answer (score 1):

Python's in-built [`os.system()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) can be used to run any command line.

You can use command `kill -9 <program_name>` with `os.system()` as below to kill the other program. You may refer to the following documentation for more clarity.

```
os.system('killall -9 <program_name>')
```

or

```
os.system('pkill <program_name>')
```

or

```
os.system('kill -9 <PID>')
```

Comment: What if I have multiple programs with the same name? It will kill all of them. See my answer for the implementation where you do not want to kill all processes with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The `call` is in the legacy API of `subprocess`. Instead use the `Popen` constructor under `subprocess` - docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects). Once you do this, you can easily send a signal to kill the process after some time as,

```
p = Popen(args)
p.kill()
```

`p.kill()` is OS independent. Hope this helps. Please do comment if you didn't understand.